# How to restrict Guest user from cloning repository

Tags: gitlab

I am using Gitlab CE 9.0 . Please tell me how to restrict a external guest user from download/clone an internal repository
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

According to [the gitlab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/permissions.html) "On public and internal projects, all users are able to perform this action".
In other words, guest users have permission to download (i.e. clone) projects they have access to.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: keep your GitLab up-to-date. 9.0 is over a year old; you will be missing a lot of security updates.

[GitLab CE User permissions table](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/permissions.html):

Second: Guests can access `public` and `internal` repositories, but not `private` ones. So you can set the project to `private`.

Third: You can flag the external users to be `external` in the `Access` tab when editing the user:

> External users cannot see internal or private projects unless access is explicitly granted. Also, external users cannot create projects or groups.